# Initializing char arrays and MISRA errors

Tags: c, arrays, array-initialization, misra

I have the following line (reduced to minimally demonstrate issue):

```
char version_text[64U] = {'\0'};
```

This line generates the following MISRA error:

```
Error[Pm023]: missing elements - braces shall be used to indicate and match the structure in the non-zero initialization of arrays and structures (MISRA C 2004 rule 9.2).
```

Why is this an error?

My current workaround is:

```
char version_text[64U] = {0};
```

which indicates that the `char` type is implemented as `signed char` by my compiler (IAR EW).

My understanding is that '\0' is a character literal and thus, should match the type `char`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, integer character constants have the type `int`, not `char`. So

```
char version_text[64U] = { '\0' };
```

and

```
char version_text[64U] = { 0 };
```

are completely equivalent (and that is independent of the signedness of `char`). Both provide an `int` constant as the sole initialiser.

That the MISRA checker complains about the first, but not the second is just an inconsistency.

However, it is probably due to the fact that a zero-initialisation is customarily done by providing just one `0`, while using integer character constants is usually only done for non-zero initialisations - where MISRA expects initialisers for all elements, if I interpret the message correctly, and the checker just doesn't look inside the character constant.

Answer (score 1):

The rule says:

> "Note also that all the elements of arrays or structures can be
>   initialised (to zero or NULL) by giving an explicit initialiser for
>   the first element only. If this method of initialisation is chosen
>   then the first element should be initialised to zero (or NULL), and
>   nested braces need not be used."

According to this, only `{0}` and `{NULL}` are compliant with MISRA, and {'\0'} isn't (even though the compiler treats them in the same way).

Comment: Or in this case, `""`, which would also be compliant.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following:

```
char version_text[64U] = { '\0', };
```

This essentially will initialize each array element to `NULL` not only the first one.
Notice a comma!